# What is Wrong with this SQL Syntax that checks if a table exists?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, syntax-error

I'm querying a server and iterating through multiple databases using PHP, but for some reason this `$sql2` query (which I have read works in countless threads) is returning a syntax error:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW DATABASES");

if (!$res){
    // Deal with error
}

while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    $db = $d['Database'];

    $sql1 = "USE $db";
    $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

    if (!$query1){
        // Deal with error
    }

    $sql2 = "IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$db'
                 AND TABLE_NAME = 'appusers'))
             BEGIN
                 SELECT * FROM `appusers`
             END";

    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    if (!$query2){
        // Deal with error
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE TABLE_S' at line 1

My MySQL Server version is 5.6.27 and my PHP interpreter is 5.6

Comment: You can't use that form of `IF` in a query, only in stored procs and functions.

Comment: And your two `(`'s aren't balanced with two opposing `)`'s.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you I will change that now, but I think Uueerdo is correct. In which case, what would I write?

Comment: Why don't you perform the inner query first, and then do the `IF` in PHP?

Comment: Here are some examples of how to use `IF` in MySQL: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php

Comment: In many languages I work in, I find it helpful to create a `TableExists` function that takes a connection, a table name, and (optionally) a schema name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an `IF` statement as a query, only in a stored procedure. You'll need to perform two separate queries.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$db'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'appusers'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['count'] != 0) {
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM appusers";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    ...
} else {
    // deal with error
}
```

Comment: What exactly is being returned to `$result`?

Comment: It's the result set of the query. You use that to fetch the rows, or call `mysqli_num_rows()`, etc.

Comment: This query returns a single row containing the count of rows in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE` that match the criteria.

Comment: I am now getting this error: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <filename>`. Why is `$result` failing?

Comment: The name of the table is `TABLES`, not `TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `if` in SQL (although mysql has a [**function** called `if`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if))

Apparently, you want to run a query if the table exists. The more common way would be to try running the query and check whether the error you get says that the table doesn't exist.

E.g. if you run the query in the `mysql` command line application, you might get this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM appusers;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.appusers' doesn't exist
```

You see two codes:

- 1146: internal mysql code (obtain this via [`mysqli_errno`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.errno.php))
- 42S02: the SQL standard error state (obtain this via [`mysqli_sqlstate`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.sqlstate.php))

In your case, checking the SQL state might be better because it covers more cases. E.g., [all of these mysql error codes map to SQL state 42S02](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html):

- 1051 - Unknown table '%s'
- 1109 - Unknown table '%s' in %s
- 1146 - Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist